# Can I call solr through thrift API?

Tags: java, solr, thrift

Solution:
 solr version: 5.40
 thrift : 0.9.3
How can I call solr request through thrift api?
(1)is exist api?
(2)or implement service above solr ?

Comment: If solr offers an API via Thrift, it is possible. If not, then not.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Client+API+Lineup

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about thrift. Looks like it could directly use the [solrj-Examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ). Otherwise you could use solr as a [restfull Service](http://yonik.com/solr-json-request-api/) via http (nur REST Service, because only POST and GET are used and you could use GET to change data).